# Mule avoid downloading file after db select statement

Tags: mule

```
<flow name="testFlow1" doc:name="testFlow1">
   <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${hostname}" port="${port}" path="dbtest" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <db:select config-ref="PostgreSQL" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT id, name, int_status FROM test]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:select>
<!--line 6 -->           <!-- <set-payload value="==no downlaod=#[payload]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>-->
        </flow>
```

when I run the application with url: host:port/dbtest, I am getting file downloaded. How can I avoid downloading file? If i enable line 6, I don't get file downloaded, instead it displays in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have used HTTP inbound 'exchange-pattern' as `request-response`. When you enable setpayload(line 6) it is returning to brower. If you dont want that, make HTTP exchange-pattern as `one- way`.

Comment: main issue is some file starts downloading, how do i avoid downloading file?

Comment: Is the above one is  your full xml config?.Did you tried by keeping as 'one-way' in exchange pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the flow by adding an 'Object-to-String' transformer. It is working for me. The file is not downloading. Here is the flow.

```
<flow name="sampleflow"> 
<http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/"doc:name="HTTP></http:listener>
<db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
<db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select id,name,designation,address from myrest]]></db:parameterized-query>
</db:select>
<object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
</flow> 
</mule>
```